# Having trouble setting flutter path - flutter commands not found

Tags: linux, macos, flutter, path, environment-variables

I've been trying to set a flutter path so I don't need to do a temporary path every single time. I'm new to using terminal and Unix (Mac user also) and don't understand how to set my path with the instructions on the site. And it doesn't help that I'm not completely sure where I out my flutter sdk. Would like to know step by step what to do.

Comment: https://flutter.io/setup-linux/#update-your-path - is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes but more detailed instructions. I am completely new to this.

Comment: Tutorial perhaps?

Comment: You may find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74337608/6921031

Answer (score 42):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Assuming you have successfully downloaded and extracted [flutter_linux_v0.5.1-beta.tar.xz](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/beta/linux/flutter_linux_v0.5.1-beta.tar.xz) (latest update until now) onto your preferred directory.

```
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Running this command in your ubuntu terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) adds flutter commands PATH variable to your system path for **temporary** session. As soon as you close the terminal, the system path is removed.

**In order for ubuntu terminal to remember flutter commands permanently, you need to:**

> 1.) open up terminal and cd to $HOME. for eg: user@linux:~$
>
> 2.) open the hidden file `.bashrc` with your desired editor. It resides in $HOME.
>
> 3.) add the following line
>   `export PATH=/home/yourname/flutter/bin:$PATH`
>   somewhere as a newline in `.bashrc` file preferably as a last line edit & save file.
>
> 4.) run `source /home/yourname/.bashrc` in terminal to process your recent changes.
>
> 5.) finally, run `echo $PATH` to see flutter dir is in your system path along with other such paths. for eg: `/home/yourname/flutter/bin`

Now close current terminal and reopen new terminal to check `flutter doctor`. It should process along with all other available flutter commands everytime now onwards. Thank you ! :)

Comment: .bashrc files is not found in my case please help ;(

Comment: user@linux:-$ ls -la | grep -i ".bashrc" (firstly, use this command to verify ".bashrc" do exists or not in you home root dir)

Comment: it present in the directory but running the .bashrc it gives permission denied. i already pemission read and write on home

Comment: it’s clear then, you need sudo permission to access bashrc file. Alternatively you can also use “.profile” file instead of bashrc which also happens to reside in same Home root dir. :)

Comment: all set but after run it gives this exception please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components.

Comment: kasunix@kasunix-Inspiron-N4030:~$ flutter doctor
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

Answer (score 4):

**Windows**

Refer to this tutorial https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

**Mac OS**

Open or create one the following files:

- `~/.profile` (Compatible with MacOS Catalina)

  `.bash_profile` (Only if your Terminal uses Bash)

add the following line at the bottom.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/flutter/bin
```

**Linux**

Open or create `~/.bash_profile` add the following line at the bottom.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/flutter/bin
```

**Linux (Ubuntu 19.04)**

Open `~/.bashrc` add the following line at the bottom: *(your path may be different)*

```
export PATH=$PATH:~developement/flutter/bin
```

**For further documentation**

https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path

Answer (score 3):

I'm using macOS Catalina version- 10.15.7 and I have updated my `$PATH` variable by following those steps:

1. Optional: Type `echo $SHELL` in your terminal. It will tell you which shell you are using. macOS Catalina uses Z shell by default.
   Output: /bin/zsh
2. Optional: Type `echo $PATH` in your terminal and hit enter. It will show you the existing paths you have already set as path variable.
   **Output**: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
3. As i'm using Z shell i have to open the `.zshrc` file. In my case i'm using `vim` editor. You can also use `nano` or `atom` editor. For opening the file type `vi ~/.zshrc` in your terminal.
4. Type `i` for Insert mode.
5. Type `export PATH="$PATH:[your_flutter_sdk_path_here]/flutter/bin"`
6. To save the file in Vim/vi, press `Esc` key then type `:w` and hit `Enter` key.
7. To quit Vim/vi by press `Esc` key then type `:x` and hit `Enter` key.
8. Finally you need a dot notation to **activate** it. Type `. ~/.zshrc` in your terminal.

Now you can check your path variable by typing `echo $PATH` in your terminal and hiting `enter` key.

**Output**: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/user/Documents/flutter/bin

Verify that the flutter command is available by running `which flutter` in your terminal.

**Output**: /Users/user/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter

Answer (score 2):

```
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when i am working VS Code / flutter with ubuntu OS. every time shows the message `flutter: command not found` . Then i set the path through VS Code integrated terminal. Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

open a terminal window and write command
    vim ~/.bash_profile
Write this in the file.

```
alias flutter="~/flutter/bin/flutter"
```

if you have extracted flutter in your root (~) folder.

save this and run this command in terminal.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Flutter path to the system path or to your `~/.profile` file.

This will help you as it has more detailed instructions, difference on using .profile vs .bashrc and usage on different shells.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Answer (score 1):

**Flutter Path Setup in MAC**

Before Setup Clone the git Flutter Folder using below Command

==> git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable

Step 1: Copy the Path of " Git Flutter Folder" and make PATH variable like below

==> export PATH="$PATH:/Users/myhome/Desktop/Flutter/bin"

Step 2: type "echo $SHELL" in terminal.It will show the type of shell which is using in your Mac

Step 3: If it is bash, type "open .bash_profile" in terminal to open the hidden "rc" file

step 4: once opened, copy  the Path variable from step 1 and paste it in .bash_profile file

Step 5: save the file

Step 6:run ==> source $HOME/.bash_profile

Step 7: Now check your path got updated by ==> echo $PATH command

Step 8:once it got listed run ==> Flutter Doctor

Step 9: If *error occurs  like "flutter commands not found"* then **"RESTART"** your Mac

Now try Flutter Doctor it will work

Answer (score 0):

it depends what shell you use,if you use bash,you can edit `~/.bash_profile`,add environment variable as `export PATH=xxx/flutter/bin:$PATH`;if use zsh,you should edit  `~/.zshrc` ,add environment variable as export `PATH=xxx/flutter/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

For bash profile users

Step 1: open terminal and type

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Step 2: Type this command (modify your folder path)

Note: I added one new folder(FlutterSDK) in my username

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/FlutterSDK/flutter/bin"
```

Step 3: Press esc

Step 4: type :wq! command to save this bash file

```
:wq!
```

Step 5: Close current terminal window & open new window

Step 6: To verify type flutter version command

```
flutter --version
```