# How to Permanently add Flutter to Path in Mac

Tags: macos, flutter, terminal

I know there are many similar answers to this however I have checked them, watched a video on it and tried countless times. I exported the flutter path to the .bashprofile and it is saved as shown in the screenshot however if I close terminal and try using a flutter command like `flutter --version` or `which flutter` or even `flutter doctor` I get `flutter not found` or `zsh: command not found: flutter`

How do I fix this so I can permanently use flutter in any directory or path

[image: terminal Picture]

[image: terminal Picture 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the path to `.bash_profile` but the error says `zsh: command not found: flutter`.

Look closely at the error, your default shell is `zsh` and not `bash`. So adding the path to `.bash_profile` doesn't help since the path is being looked up for in `.zshrc`  instead.

Here's how you can add the path to `.zshrc` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530176/5066615

Comment: Thanks man, the link didnt help been on that but knowing it was a .zshrc error helped. got it fixed

Answer (score 19):

Please follow the steps below:

1. Open the Terminal.
2. Type: `nano ~/.zshrc`
3. Type: `export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH`

[image]

4. Press `control+x` to Exit
5. Type: `source ~/.zshrc`
6. Restart the Terminal.
7. Verify by typing `flutter --version`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Adding FLUTTER PPATH to terminal permanently

**Step:1**

TYPE:  `echo $SHELL`

- This will tell which SHELL you are using (bash or Z shell)

**Step:2**

TYPE: `$HOME/.bashrc`

- If it shows ***file does not exists***, then you need to create new zshrc file

(Only if the above error accours) TYPE:  `touch ~/.zshrc`      // this will create a new zshrc file

**Step 3:**

TYPE: `open  $HOME/.zshrc`  //to open the **zshrc** file

- Add the flutter bin path for setting to the terminal permanently in **zshrc** file

TYPE: `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/development/flutter/bin"`

**Step 4:**

TYPE:  `source $HOME/.zshrc` //to refresh current terminal window

Now u can run flutter cmds without adding path all times