# Flutter doctor not found

Tags: flutter, path

I am tryin to write flutter codes in my MacBook but when I write Flutter doctor on my Terminal,ıt says command not found.I am trying to add path but ıt doesn't matter, ı can't add it
There is a photo about my problem.I hope somebody can understand that problem.

.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTVwo.jpg)

ı was expecting write flutter but  ı couldn't take any result when I write Flutter doctor.

Comment: seems like flutter sdk path not apecified in $PATH 
Please check this.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63209387/4373661

Comment: I did it but it didn't work but thanks for  replying

Comment: I think i've done things in zsh that i didnt understand, so it does not work right now and it says command not found
Than i added 

export PATH=~/Users/salmangroup/Desktop/development/flutter/bin/flutter/bin:$PATH

This line to 
vim ~/.bash_profile

and

vim $HOME/bashrc

But when i try to run flutter doctor i dont have reply it says flutter doctor cannot found
And I have sdk

Comment: These links might help :

link1 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh/11530176

link2 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh/11530176

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed [flutter sdk](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos/mobile-android?tab=download), then after you have to assign the flutter path in your .zshrc file.

**How to find .zshrc file?**

just go to your finder and open in enclosing folder and then using this shortcut key **cmd+shift+.(dot)** then you will find .zshrc file if not then create by your own and provide your flutter sdk path like this and save file.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/yourpcname/foldername/fluttersdk/bin"
```

that's it now run **flutter doctor** it will work now.

Comment: Their screenshot indicates that they use `bash` and not `zsh` so they probably need to use `.bash_profile` and not `.zshrc`

Comment: yes but it doesn't effect anywhere i'm using throw .zshrc and it is working fine.but thanks for the info.

Comment: I think i've done things in zsh that i didnt understand, so it does not work right now and it says command not found
Than i added 

export PATH=~/Users/salmangroup/Desktop/development/flutter/bin/flutter/bin:$PATH

This line to 
vim ~/.bash_profile

and

vim $HOME/bashrc

But when i try to run flutter doctor i dont have reply it says flutter doctor cannot found
And I have sdk